# Lua import strings from file

Tags: string, variables, lua

I can't load my user.db into Lua.

user.db contains:

```
user1="XYZ1"
user2="Xzy2"
....
admin="ZXY"
```

Some Bash and Python scripts use the same db.

For Bash e.g. I used the `source user.db` command, but I don't have a clue for lua.

Should be something similiar outside?! I tried the `require` function but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dofile "user.db"   -- try this
```

Comment: Thank you this works! I just had to fill in the full path to the file :)